# IEnumerable Except not working

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have the following code

```
/// <summary>
///     Calculates the date with a number of working days offset from today by
///     calculating a set of dates that exclude weekends and holidays, then
///     skipping forward the required number of days.
/// </summary>
public static DateTime AddWorkingDays(int workingDays, DateTime startDate)
{
    var workDaysQuery = from n in Enumerable.Range(0, (workingDays + 14) * 2)
                        let date = startDate.AddDays(n)
                        where (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) && (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                        select date;
    var publicHolidays = GetPublicHolidays();

    var daysWorking = workDaysQuery.Except(publicHolidays).ToArray(); // why does this still include the publicHolidays ?

    return daysWorking.Skip(workingDays).First();
}
```

However the Except does not remove the public holidays.

The time component of the public holiday dates are all zero.

Comment: Try to replace `select date;` with `select date.Date;` and replace `publicHolidays` with `publicHolidays.Select(x => x.Date)` (this is needed if values of `publicHolidays` contain time)

Comment: My guess: the time component of `startDate` is not zero. Change it to `let date = startDate.Date.AddDays(n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static DateTime AddWorkingDays(int workingDays, DateTime startDate)
{
    var workDaysQuery = from n in Enumerable.Range(0, (workingDays + 14) * 2)
                        let date = startDate.AddDays(n)
                        where (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                        && (date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                        select date.Date; //Remove the time component

    //The following change is not needed if you know for sure that 
    //values returned by GetPublicHolidays() will not include a time component
    var publicHolidays = GetPublicHolidays().Select(x => x.Date);

    var daysWorking = workDaysQuery.Except(publicHolidays).ToArray(); 

    return daysWorking.Skip(workingDays).First();
}
```

Basically, if two `DateTime` values have the same date (year, month, and day) but different time component, then the system will consider them as non-equal.

What the code above does is that it uses the [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get only the date component (without the time). This way, the equality checks (done by `Except` internally) will be correct.

Comment: ah workDaysQuery had dates with 12 pm and publicHoilidays had dates with 12 am.